# Sprinkler piping leaking

Tags: leak

Piping leaking at the shown joint. Simple as wrapping the pipe again in thread tape and potentially replacing the nut?

[image]

Comment: irrigation or fire?

Comment: Irrigation system

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have copper pipe with a sweated (soldered) union fitting. From your text it sounds like the leak is in the nut area of the union?

Unions usually seal with direct metal-on-metal contact, though some have an o-ring. They don't seal on the threaded nut in any case. You can loosen the nut, separate the union, inspect the faces for damage or debris (and o-ring if applicable), clean if needed, and then re-assemble and tighten the nut.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is called union fitting. Those are used to connect two pipes that can be disconnected if needed.

The seal is between the two parts.

Shut off the water and disconnect the union to inspect why is it leaking.

You can use some plumber grease or even plumber putty to seal it better.

Unfortunately your is soldered so replacing it will not be so easy but possible.

If you are unscrewing it use two wrenches. One to hold (in your case the upper pipe), one to turn the nut.